# Shopping cart - number of items in cart CSS

Tags: html, css, asp.net

As we all have seen in popular websites , there is a small icon on the `top-right` of the icon of cart ! I have to use something like that in my ASP .NET web-page.

[image]

How do i get this icon to the top-right of the cart icon ..

The icon of the cart is a normal bootstrap one and the css for the number of items in cart is as follows :

```
.badge {
  padding-left: 9px;
  padding-right: 9px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
  -moz-border-radius: 9px;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.label-warning[href],
.badge-warning[href] {
  background-color: #c67605;
}
```

**NOTE:** all the menu items shown in the image including the cart icon are in `ul-li` list .

```
 <li>
      <a href="Cart1.aspx" class="icon-shopping-cart" style="font-size: 25px"><asp:Label ID="lblCartCount" runat="server" CssClass="badge badge-warning"  ForeColor="White"/></a>
</li>
```

**EDIT:** The cart count is just nearly how i want it to be , but could it go a bit more to the top of the cart icon ? like about 3-5px?

[image]

Comment: post the code at https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Make the anchor tags inline.... and place the cart image anchor at the end...

Comment: by inline do you mean `display:inline` css?? if you can , can u please show me some code or a fiddle or some resource?

Comment: @Rusty : I tried to add all the css and html of the page. But the fiddle looked [horrible](http://jsfiddle.net/LhrLe0j6/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align: top;` to your counter, in this case to the ID `#lblCartCount`

```
#lblCartCount {
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Here's an **[online example](http://jsfiddle.net/LhrLe0j6/1/)**

Comment: aaghhh .. thank you very much! `vertical-align : top` did the magic!

Comment: this did work but , what if i want the counter to stick to the top of the cart icon ??

Comment: You could give it a `margin-left: -18px;` for example but this will make the counter kinda go behind the the **cart image** if you really want it to be over the cart image then give it a `position: absolute; margin-left: -18px;`

Comment: That worked very well , thank you ! I am sorry if i am stretching this , but could the `cartCount` a bit more to the top ..?? Please see the screenshot i have added in my question! Thank you!

Comment: you can do this by giving a negative **margin-top**. Example `margin-top:-5px;` alongside `position: absolute; `

Comment: I dont know why this isnt making any difference even if i give margi-top : -50px!

Comment: did you give it the position absolute? **[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/LhrLe0j6/2/)**

Comment: giving position absolute moves the `cartCount` to the bottom left of the `cart-icon`..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74046/discussion-between-chun-and-abhishek-ghosh).

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS and it will work accurately to change the background color according to your choice

```css
.badge {
    font-size: 12px;
    background: green;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2px 6px;
    margin: -10px 0 0 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```