# Shopping cart with circle counter to the top right not rendering properly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the layout of the cart like this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313879/shopping-cart-number-of-items-in-cart-css). But not being able to put it to the top right of the cart. My thing is a bit different, when on a big screen the bubble should display on top right of the text CART while on a small screen it should display on top right of cart image.

**NOTE:** The action_bar sticks to the top when scrolling, so I guess position fixed cant be used for 'total' div.

**HTML**

```
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div id="action_bar">
    <div id="cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i><div id="total">1</div></div>
    <div id="filter"><i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#action_bar {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#cart {
    right: 0;
    width: 15%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: #20AC76;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
    border: #1C9767 1px solid;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: left;
}

.fa fa-shopping-cart {
    float: left;
}

#total {
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #20AC76;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

#cart:after {
    content: '  Cart';
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    #cart {
        right: 0;
        width: 20%;
        height: 10%;
        background-color: #20AC76;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        padding: 10px;
        float: right;
        border: #1C9767 1px solid;
        font-size: 22px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #cart:after {
        content: normal;
    }

    #total {
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put #cart on "position:relative" and #total in position:absolute, now you can move #total with left property

```css
#action_bar {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#cart {
    right: 0;
    width: 15%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: #20AC76;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
    border: #1C9767 1px solid;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: left;
  position:relative;
}

.fa fa-shopping-cart {
    float: left;
}

#total {
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #20AC76;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 1rem; 
    position:absolute; 
    left: 40px
}

#cart:after {
    content: '  Cart';
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    #cart {
        right: 0;
        width: 20%;
        height: 10%;
        background-color: #20AC76;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        padding: 10px;
        float: right;
        border: #1C9767 1px solid;
        font-size: 22px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #cart:after {
        content: normal;
    }

    #total {
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div id="action_bar">
    <div id="cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i><div id="total">1</div></div>
    <div id="filter"><i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The counter goes below the image.

Comment: Add z-index on #total , like z-index:99999

Comment: it doesnt follow the cart top right when browser resize

Comment: In mediaquery change content: 'Cart'

Comment: but I will need that content

Comment: Yes, but remove #cart:after {content: normal;} on mediaquery

Comment: Then the word CART will show up in that breakpoint too which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @jose-bernalte works pretty well, but you have to add a top to the #total for it to be pulled up. Something like this works nicely:

```
position: absolute;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: red;
color: white;
font-size: 8pt;
text-align: center;
line-height: 20px;
left: 25px;
top: 0;
z-index: 50;
```

I also changed the color and the font size to be a bit more dominate, and added a z-index to make sure it's on top. With this, you can display the circle above a shopping cart icon.

All in all, your html should look a bit like this (you'll have to come up with your cart class, and add a little font-awesome, because, well, it's awesome):

```
<div>
    <a class="cart" rel="tooltip" title="My Cart" data-placement="bottom" href="cart.html"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
    <div id="cart-total">1</div>
</div>
```