# How to put the number at top right corner of cart icon?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I would like to place a number at top right corner of the font awesome cart icon.

I have created this simple html.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <i class="fa" style="font-size:24px">&#xf07a;</i>
    <span> 5 </span>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The result is as follows.

[image]

How can i make the number appear the top right corner of the cart icon as shown in the following image?

[image]

I appreciate any help from css experts. Thanks!

Comment: Share your code and show what you tried yet

Comment: read about position property

Comment: i know how to place on top of image. how do you place on top of an <i> element?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This appears to have been answered previously: 
[Shopping cart - number of items in cart CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313879/shopping-cart-number-of-items-in-cart-css)

Modified the code to suit your request:
http://jsfiddle.net/LhrLe0j6/361/

```
<i class="fa" style="font-size:24px">&#xf07a;</i>
<span class='badge badge-warning' id='lblCartCount'> 5 </span>
```

CSS:

```
.badge {
  padding-left: 9px;
  padding-right: 9px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
  -moz-border-radius: 9px;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.label-warning[href],
.badge-warning[href] {
  background-color: #c67605;
}
#lblCartCount {
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: -10px; 
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can achieve the same thing without the extra span tag using the pseudo elements of the same `i` tag. The value can be specified in the `value` attribute of the corresponding icon.

```css
.badge:after{
content:attr(value);
font-size:12px;
background: red;
border-radius:50%;
padding:3px;
position:relative;
left:-8px;
top:-10px;
opacity:0.9;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="fa badge" style="font-size:24px" value=5>&#xf07a;</i>
```

Answer (score 2):

Warp the elements with a div like this,

```css
.wrapper{
position: relative;
}

.wrapper span{
position: absolute;
top: -2px;
right: -2px; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="wrapper">
  <i class="fa" style="font-size:24px">&#xf07a;</i>
  <span> 5 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
span{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 900;
    position: absolute;
    border: solid blue;
    border-radius: 60%;
    height: 14px;
    width: 8px;
    background:blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <i class="fa" style="font-size:24px">&#xf07a;</i>
    <span> 5 </span>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thanks! is it possible to overlap a little like shown in the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
By using fontawesome and bootstrap 5    

<div>
     <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart "></i>
     <span
       class="badge bg-danger"
       style="idth: 30px;
       height: 30px;
       padding: 15.2px 7.8px;
       font-size: 27px;
       border-radius: 26px;
       transform: perspective(0px) translate(-12px) rotate(0deg) scale(0.50);
       transform-origin: top;
       padding-right: 0;
       padding-top: 0.2px;
       padding-left: 0.2px;
       text-align: center;border-width: 48px;
     ">2</span>
    </div>
```

[screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5yf9.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34492712)