# How to change cart icon state using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onclick, state, cart

I have two components, one will contain a button that will trigger the cart icon change when clicked, while the second component will contain the cart icon to be changed. I have tried but i have not been able to achieve this.[Here is an image to explain better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fABh.jpg)

Component A

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'

const Cart = () => {
const [itemCount, setItemCount] = useState('');
return (
<div>
  <button
        style={{width: '10%', height: '10%', padding:'20px'}}
        onClick={() => {
          setItemCount(itemCount + 1);
        }}
      >
        {" "}
    </button>
</div>
)
}

export default Cart
```

Component B

```
import React from 'react'
import Cart from './Cart'

const CartShow = (props) => {
return (
<div style={{border: '2px solid red', background: 'black', width: '30%', margin: '100px', 
padding: '30px'}}>
  <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M9 22C9.55228 22 10 21.5523 10 21C10 20.4477 9.55228 20 9 20C8.44772 20 8 20.4477 
8 21C8 21.5523 8.44772 22 9 22Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" 
stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    <path d="M20 22C20.5523 22 21 21.5523 21 21C21 20.4477 20.5523 20 20 20C19.4477 20 19 
20.4477 19 21C19 21.5523 19.4477 22 20 22Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke- 
linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    <path d="M1 1H5L7.68 14.39C7.77144 14.8504 8.02191 15.264 8.38755 15.5583C8.75318 15.8526 
9.2107 16.009 9.68 16H19.4C19.8693 16.009 20.3268 15.8526 20.6925 15.5583C21.0581 15.264 
21.3086 14.8504 21.4 14.39L23 6H6" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" 
stroke-linejoin="round"/>
  {props.itemCount}</svg>
    <Cart/>
</div>
)
}

export default CartShow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your code works except the state change. following should work(not tested):

Component A

```
const Cart = (props) => 
<div>
  <button
        style={{width: '10%', height: '10%', padding:'20px'}}
        onClick={() => props.setItemCount(props.itemCount + 1)}
      >
        {" "}
    </button>
</div>

export default Cart
```

Component B

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import Cart from './Cart'

const CartShow = () => {
const [itemCount, setItemCount] = useState(0);
return (
<div style={{border: '2px solid red', background: 'black', width: '30%', margin: '100px', 
padding: '30px'}}>
  <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M9 22C9.55228 22 10 21.5523 10 21C10 20.4477 9.55228 20 9 20C8.44772 20 8 20.4477 
8 21C8 21.5523 8.44772 22 9 22Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" 
stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    <path d="M20 22C20.5523 22 21 21.5523 21 21C21 20.4477 20.5523 20 20 20C19.4477 20 19 
20.4477 19 21C19 21.5523 19.4477 22 20 22Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke- 
linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    <path d="M1 1H5L7.68 14.39C7.77144 14.8504 8.02191 15.264 8.38755 15.5583C8.75318 15.8526 
9.2107 16.009 9.68 16H19.4C19.8693 16.009 20.3268 15.8526 20.6925 15.5583C21.0581 15.264 
21.3086 14.8504 21.4 14.39L23 6H6" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" 
stroke-linejoin="round"/>
  {itemCount}</svg>
    <Cart itemCount={itemCount} setItemCount={setItemCount} />
</div>
)
}

export default CartShow
```

Edit: to show the numbers on on the cart, check this link: [How to put the number at top right corner of cart icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304169/how-to-put-the-number-at-top-right-corner-of-cart-icon/51304449#51304449)

Comment: thank you, i have implemented it but onClick of the button, i want number '1' to show on top of the cart icon. how do i go about it please?

Comment: @Annie please check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304169/how-to-put-the-number-at-top-right-corner-of-cart-icon

Answer (score 0):

Since `Cart` is a child of `CartShow` you should move the state to `CartShow` ( or have a different parent component that contains both of them ). Then pass a func down to `Cart` to update `itemCount`

Comment: alright, let me try it out

Comment: the example by @earthguestg is pretty much what I had in mind also